# Calculations using a list with operations with numbers python

Tags: python, list, operations

I am trying to use a list that has operations attached to them, but i can't get the numbers out of the list. Here is the list.

```
mylist=["+1", "-2", "*2"]
```

I was wondering if there was a way to put them together as a float, and then do the operation so it would do 1-2*2 and output the answer. Smaller the better. thanks :) the expected output is -2.

Comment: These are strings?

Comment: `mylist=[+1, -2, *2]` is illegal in Python.

Comment: Are you attempting a RPN calculator?

Comment: Are you trying to parse expressions?

Comment: How do you get the list, from user input? Again, the list you display is not valid Python.

Comment: Yes from the user @schwobaseggl

Comment: @Alpha What is the starting value, `0`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes they are. Info from the user is a String, i believe.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes

Comment: @James yea basicly

Comment: @DYZ i omitted the quotations, my bad. They are all in a str type.

Comment: What is the expcted result for the given list: -2 or -3

Comment: @schwobaseggl  -2

Comment: @Alpha You should put that in your post as it clears up the precedence of operations

Comment: i do apologies. its late and i just needed a answer. didn't really think that far ahead :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to map symbols to operations (that are all defined in [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)) and [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to parse the strings in order to avoid evil [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). This applies the operations in the list from left to right, regardless of mathematical operator precedence:

```
import re
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv  # use 'floordiv' for integer division

def calc(lst):
    ops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv}
    result = 0
    for x in lst:
        op, num = re.match(r'([+\-\*/])(\d+)', x).groups()
        result = ops[op](result, int(num))
    return result

>>> calc(['+1', '-2', '*2'])
-2
>>> calc(['+1', '-2', '*2', '+7', '*3'])
15
```

Comment: Does +1-2*2 really evaluate to -2?

Comment: @DYZ ...which the OP expects, as it turned out :)

Comment: I guess you win, then :)

Answer (score 0):

By treating your example as a string, it is possible to compute the output after each operation listed, assuming the input is treated with precedence from left to right:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re
token = namedtuple('token', 'operator, value')
mylist="[+1, -2, *2]"
data = re.findall('[\+\-\*]|\d+', mylist)
final_data = [data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)] #create tokenized list
tokens = [token(a, int(b)) for a, b in final_data] 
operations = {'+':lambda x,y:x+y, '-':lambda x, y:x-y, '*':lambda x, y:x*y}
total_val = 0
for token in tokens:
   total_val = operations[token.operator](total_val, token.value)
```

Output:

```
-2
```

Comment: Why does 1-2*2 evaluate to -2?

Comment: @DYZ unless the OP clarifies with regard to the proper order, this answer treats the data with precedence from left to right, as I believe adding `(` and `)` is out of scope of this question.